# Getting 'Invoke-Sqlcmd' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet when running powershell scripts in scheduled task as a not administrator

Tags: powershell

Why do i get

> 'Invoke-Sqlcmd' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet when running powershell scripts as a scheduled task as a not administrator.

if I add `Import-Module "sqlps" -DisableNameChecking` to the script it?

Comment: Is there a pending edit to this? The last sentence is very pertinent and incomplete. What happens?

Comment: Try `Import-Module “sqlps” -verbose` in that task of yours, and capture the verbose output into a file to debug. Most likely some of the required files are not available on `$env:path`.